# asp.net mvc output caching issue with non standard url dialect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, outputcache, cyrillic

I have an unusual issue that I have ran in to with asp.net mvc caching. I have applied the caching attributes to my controller actions. It works nicely on URL's which are standard alphanumeric url's eg. http://www.website.com/product/1234/myproduct

However the output caching does not work - controller action gets triggered on subsequent requests if the url contains any encoded type letters eg. cyrillic  http://www.website.com/product/1234/каран-для

I cant work out why but I suspect some hidden exception is occurring somewhere.

Has any one ran in to this issue before with mvc output caching?

Comment: before down vote for others answer!just read it!i told you lots of browsers not all browsers. and i suggest you to take your time in w3schools basics!

Comment: and I suggest you read the question better in future and address the question raised!